# How is this custom HTML attribute used?

Tags: html, css

I opened the source code of [devdocs.io](http://www.devdocs.io) and saw this line:

`<button type="button" aria-label="Back" class="_header-btn" data-back hidden>`

I've read about custom HTML attributes with the `data` prefix but I'm confused about their usage here. First, there isn't any value given to the `data-back` attribute. Second, I don't understand that `hidden` thing at all. What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: you are free to add attriute like you want and use them in CSS/JS, or in any other way ... there is no reason, it's simply HTML, you need to read more about it, so google it

Comment: maybe some javascript is looking for it?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you come across something in web and you don't understand how it works, if you ask about it on SO without doing any research, your question will attract downvotes and is less likely to provide a quality answer. And it's normal, if you think about it... Instead of (re)searching yourself, you are asking others to do it for you. With that out of the way...

---

HTML allows any attributes to be declared on any standard or custom tag, besides the ones that are already part of the spec. Other than name collisions and naming standards, there are no limits.

Here's [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2) for naming attributes.

Both JavaScript and CSS can add functionality or change the display rules and/or behavior of DOM elements based on both attribute names and values.

On top of that, certain libraries, (like jQuery, for example) have defined methods for conveniently  getting/setting attributes to DOM elements, provided they follow some basic naming patterns. One of the most commonly used is `data-*`.
[$.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) is a jQuery collection of methods designed to...

> *Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.*

Other libraries use certain naming patterns to add extra features and logic to DOM elements, (i.e.: `ng-*` for AngularJS). Another interesting naming pattern used in Angular (v2 and above) is the `[prop]=""` pattern, which allows a user to directly bind a value to a JavaScript property of the DOM object associated with the tag.
For example,

```
<span [style]="{color:'red'}">I'd be red in Angular 2+</span>
```

... will make the `style.color` property of the DOM element associated with the `<span>` have the value `"red"`, which is similar in behavior as `style="color:red;"` but accesses the JavaScript property of the DOM element directly, the cool part of it being that whatever is between quotes in `[prop]=""` is evaluated as JavaScript by Angular and the result of the evaluation is mapped to the corresponding property of the DOM element.

---

As per your specific code:

```
<button type="button" aria-label="Back" class="_header-btn" data-back hidden>
```

..., `data-back` is a custom empty attribute declared on the tag. Empty attributes are used when defining the attribute is enough and a `value` is not needed. It's all in the spec, linked above.

[`hidden`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-hidden-attribute) is a standard attribute.

---

In conclusion, attributes are an extremely powerful tool when working with HTML, as it allows developers to add custom functionality and behavior to standard or custom tags.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As a matter of fact, I did a lot of research and didn't find what I needed. I don't understand this: `data-back hidden`. Clearly, here `data-back` should be an attribute, but there isn't an equals sign and quotes to enter the value of the attribute. They use `hidden` next to `data-back`. How is this possible?

Comment: They are 2 completely different attributes. `data-back` does something and `hidden` does something else. What exactly, I can't tell you, as I have no idea what libraries you are using. The point here being: ***they are not standard attributes***. The logic for those has been defined in custom libraries/scripts loaded in the project. They are not part of spec.

Comment: @LearningMath, as per your previous (re)search on the subject, make a habit of adding the results/conclusions you got from your research **into the question** and also asking about the specific part that's unclear. In other words, the above comment should have been the *meat* of your question. You shouldn't have asked it inside a comment. Cheers!

Comment: [`hidden`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/editing.html#element-attrdef-global-hidden) *is* a standard attribute.

Comment: Correct, @Alohci. Updated. Thank you.